# What is the difference between INSERT and CURRENT?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-text

Quick question, What is the difference between INSERT and CURRENT?  I am using Tkinter text area to display text. My question deals with the insert function, there are 4 options that I am aware of: INSERT, CURRENT, END and raw values.

1. When I use the INSERT parameter, sometimes the input text would be placed in between existing text rather at the end .
2. If I use the CURRENT parameter, sometimes the input text will appear at the beginning of the text field.
3. When I use the END parameter (self explanatory), the input text appears at the end how I prefer it

Comment: INSERT is the index of the insertion cursor, CURRENT is the index under the mouse pointer.

Comment: What is the insertion cursor/mouse pointer? Those terms are a bit vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `insert` represents the insertion cursor (where text will be inserted via the keyboard), and `current` represents the character closest to the mouse.

From the official [tcl/tk documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/text.htm#m71), upon which tkinter is built:

> Two marks have special significance. First, the mark **insert** is associated with the insertion cursor .... Second, the mark **current** is associated with the character closest to the mouse and is adjusted automatically to track the mouse position and any changes to the text in the widget (one exception: **current** is not updated in response to mouse motions if a mouse button is down; the update will be deferred until all mouse buttons have been released).